# What is the difference between this function call?

Tags: javascript

```
setInterval("RunSlide()", 5000);
```

First, call a function with brackets and quotes.

```
setInterval("RunSlide", 5000);
```

Second, call a function without brackets but still using a quotes.

```
setInterval(Runslide, 5000);
```

Third, call a function without brackets and quotes.

```
RunSlide();
```

Fourth, call a function with brackets.

```
RunSlide;
```

Fifth, call a function without brackets.

Comment: Mentioning a function name without parentheses does **not** call the function. It is merely a reference to the function object.

Comment: what is the 'reference to the function object' mean? I don't understand yet about 'function object'

Comment: Your fifth option _call a function without brackets_ is a variable name since JavaScript has no way to know you mean call a function.

Comment: @EgaRana In JavaScript, functions are objects. The name of the function works like a variable name that refers to the function object. When it's followed by the `( )` operator, a function call is made. When it's not, it's just a reference to the object just like any other reference to an object.

Comment: By the way, because of this question I discovered a bug in Firefox 13's web console: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774365

Answer (score 2):

Even though the result might be the same there are differences in using the different argument types.

---

- `setInterval ("argument as string", delay)`

  This will cause the same behavior as passing the string to `eval` and is therefore **not** recommended (for the same exact reasons, more on that subject can be found [on the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!)).

<sup>**example snippet:**</sup>

```
 setInterval ("console.log ('hello world');", 100);
```

---

- `setInterval (func_reference, delay, param1, param2, ...)`

  This will cause the function pointed to by `func` to be called, this is the recommended option. If you call the function this way you will also be able to pass parameters to the function to be executed.

<sup>**example snippet(s):**</sup>

```
function say_it (word1, word2) {
  console.log (word1 + " " + word2);
}

setInterval (say_it, 100, "hello", "world");
```

```
setInterval (function (word1, word2) {
   console.log (word1 + " " + word2);
}, 100, "hello", "world);
```

---

#### Note(s)

Calling `setInterval` with the first argument as a string containing **only** the name of a function is utterly pointless, the function will not be executed. It's the same as writing the below somewhere in your code.

```
alert;
```

The differences between `RunSlide();` and `RunSlide;` should be quite obvious after the above example, one will call the function referenced by the name *RunSlide*, the other will not (do anything at all).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @refp, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @EgaRana Don't forget to accept the answer to mark the question as solved, read all about by following this link: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).